# Execute get-childitem, but iterate in reverse order?

Tags: powershell

I have a folder full of 500,00+ files. I'm trying to iterate through this folder and run some logic to determine if we can delete unneeded files. The problem is this process needs to run semi-regularly and the new files that need to be deleted are currently at the end of the list it seems.

I put together the following list of code to sort through it all:

```
gci $RPT | %{
$flag = 0;

$number = [int]($_.Name | select-string -pattern "\d{12}" -Allmatches).Matches.Value

if ($submidlist -match "^$number$"){
    if ($_ -notmatch "acct\.csv|jpd\.csv|jss\.pdf|jman\.pdf|3600\.pdf|cont\.pdf|msl\.txt|pres\.pdf|tray\.pdf|qual\.pdf|zipl\.pdf"){
        echo "DELETE SUBMID $_"
        remove-item $RPT\$_

        $count++
        $totalcount++
        $flag = 1;
    }
}

if ($jobidlist -match "^$number$"){
    if ($_ -match "acct\.csv|jpd\.csv|jss\.pdf|jman\.pdf|3600\.pdf|cont\.pdf|msl\.txt|pres\.pdf|tray\.pdf|qual\.pdf|zipl\.pdf"){
        echo "DELETE JOBID $_"
        remove-item $RPT\$_
        $count++
        $totalcount++
        $flag = 1;
    }
}

}
```

Currently, running the above script takes over 24 hours and it still doesn't make it to the end of the list. Is there a way to optimize this or reverse the order that get-childitem iterates through this folder?

Comment: maybe a rewrite is needed. 500,000 files shouldnt take 24 hours. What is the criteria for deletion?

Comment: There are two large lists of numbers (one is around 5000 and the other is 20000), $submidlist and $jobidlist. Each file is trimmed down to just the number and compared to each list, if one matches it then deletes it based off the extension. Honestly, I may need to trim down the criteria, because it's probably adding to the run time.

Comment: Yeah looking at it i think i have a idea of what you are trying to do. Should be a easy fix

Comment: Are both list just 12 digits numbers?

Comment: A number with 12 digits wouldn't fit to an [int], should require an [int64]. Also the `-AllMatches` parameter  should only be necessary for multiple 12 digits in a single file name, which doesn't match with the rest of the code.

Comment: Both lists are actually all 6 digit numbers, I was casting it to [int] to remove the padded zeros.

Comment: is there padding before and after or just before on the 6 digits?

Comment: Wait are you trying to delete the files or the folder if it doesnt match those files in it?

Answer (score 0):

```
function Delete-Items($List, [string]$ListName){

    $DoNotDelete = @("acct.csv","jpd.csv","jss.pdf","jman.pdf","3600.pdf","cont.pdf","msl.txt","pres.pdf","tray.pdf","qual.pdf","zipl.pdf")

    $List = $List | %{
        "*$_*"
    }
    Get-ChildItem C:\TEST\56381643\ -Recurse -Include $List -Directory | %{
        Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Exclude $DoNotDelete -Recurse | %{          
                echo "DELETE $ListName $($_.name | select-string -pattern "\d{12}")"
                Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -WhatIf
        }
    } 
}

#Example Usage
$JobList = @(
    098765432109
    123456789012

)

$SubmitList = @(
    234567890123
)

Delete-Items -List $JobList -ListName JOBID
Delete-Items -List $SubmitList -ListName SUBMID
```

Lets go over a basic rundown of whats happening in the function.

We have a array of files not to delete

We turn the `$list` numbers into wildcards by adding a `*` before and after each item in the array. We then only search for those directories that contain those numbers.

We then use another `Get-ChildItem to get the files in each directory but exclude the ones mentioned in`$DoNotDelete`.

If you want to delete the files delete the `-Whatif` on the `remove-item`